# Getting "Reference update failed" when creating new branch with github API

Tags: ruby, github, git-branch, github-api

I am trying to create a new branch off master via the Github API, but I am getting a "Reference update failed" error. Here is my ruby code:

```
def self.create_ref access_token, github_user, github_repo, ref
    sha=nil
    url = "https://api.github.com/repos/#{github_user}/#{github_repo}/git/refs/heads/master"
RestClient.get(url,{params:{access_token:access_token},accept:'json'}){ |response, request, result| 
       puts response      
       sha=JSON.parse(response)['object']['sha']
    }  
    url = "https://api.github.com/repos/#{github_user}/#{github_repo}/git/refs"
    RestClient.post(url,{ref:name,sha:sha }.to_json,{params:{access_token:access_token},accept:'json'}){ |response, request, result| 
       puts response
}    
end
```

Is using the master sha code the wrong approach to create a new ref?

Comment: What value are you using for the `ref` property when [making the `POST` request to create the branch](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#create-a-reference)?

You'll get a "Reference update failed" error if you don't provide a fully-qualified reference (e.g., `refs/heads/some-branch-name`). Could that be the issue you're seeing?

Comment: [This Gist](https://gist.github.com/jasonrudolph/10727108) might help. It demonstrates the "Reference update failed" error when you don't provide a fully-qualified ref name, and it demonstrates successful creation of the branch when providing a fully-qualified ref name.